# GROUP BY using another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables **users** and **votes** and some users can have same `unq_id`

I'm trying to select all **distinct** `unq_id` from **users** and sort them by `votes` from **votes** table.

But the results are not how I expected, the votes are duplicated. You can see in below image

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.unq_id, COUNT(v.id) AS count_votes
FROM users u
INNER JOIN votes v
ON u.unq_id = v.unq_id
WHERE u.unq_id <> ''
GROUP BY u.unq_id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0bb35/1

Expected results:

```
3fyx6 - 3
9kx9mq - 1
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Your table relation looks weird. You should have a unique identifier to join to which you don't have currently. That can't work.

Comment: Usually no need to do SELECT DISTINCT when GROUP BY.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Perhaps MySQL.)

Comment: you should `GROUP BY users.unq_id`

Comment: @TheFlash same output.. the votes are duplicated

Comment: @MaliiAlii try my answer. It should work. I am unable to test on sqlfiddle

Comment: @juergend the users can make a team so they have the same unq_id

Comment: @FallAndLearn doesn't work because of id column

Comment: Do you need the `users` table at all in this query? Are there `unq_id` values in `votes` which won't have any matching rows in `users`, and it's those values you want to exclude?

Comment: @MaliiAlii:Sql Fiddle seems to be down,can you post the same fiddle on data.stackexchange.com

Comment: #1: If some users can have the same `unq_id` its not unique. #2: You don't need to join the `users` table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes because some users have no votes at all and i want to put them on the list.

Comment: @TheGameiswar ok. just a moment! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired result you don't need to join to `users`, but based on your comment *"some users have no votes at all and i want to put them on the list"* you should aggregate before a LEFT join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   u.unq_id, 
   COALESCE(v.count_votes, 0)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
 ( select unq_id, count(*) as count_votes
   from votes
   group by unq_id
 ) v
ON u.unq_id = v.unq_id
WHERE u.unq_id <> '';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.unq_id, COUNT(v.id) AS count_votes
```

to

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.unq_id, COUNT(distinct v.id) AS count_votes
```

And see if it helps :)

Comment: And if you want to include users without any registered votes, I would change from inner join to a left join :)

Comment: The problem with the duplicates is the nature of joins when you join two tables with duplicated data in both of the joined columns

Comment: Of course adding `DISTINCT` to the count fixes the wrong result, but it hides a wrong data model/bad query where you do an n:m-join instead of 1:n.

Comment: @dnoeth so is better to use a subquery ?

Comment: @MaliiAlii if you can't avoid duplicated data in column 'unq_id' in the users table, I would personally use the 'id' column (and call it, for example user_id). and have another column in the votes table (also called user_id). If you would then join these tables on the new 'user_id' column, you would not need to use distinct

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
select distinct v.unq_id, count(distinct v.id) as votes
from users u
inner join votes v
on u.unq_id = v.unq_id
group by v.unq_id
order by 2 desc;
```

But I'd rather use subquery, I think it would be much faster:

```
select v.unq_id, count(v.unq_id) as votes
from votes v
where v.unq_id in (select unq_id from users group by unq_id)
group by v.unq_id
order by 2 desc;
```